# How can I add blank top rows to an xlsx file using the xlsx package?

Tags: r, xlsx

I would like to add two blank rows to the top of an xlsx file that I create.

so far I have tried:

```
library("xlsx")
fn1 <- 'test1.xlsx'
fn2 <- 'test2.xlsx'

write.xlsx(matrix(rnorm(25),5),fn1)

wb <- loadWorkbook(fn1)
rows <- getRows(getSheets(wb)[[1]])
for(i in 1:length(rows)) 
    rows[[i]]$setRowNum(as.integer(i+1))

saveWorkbook(wb,fn2)
```

But `test2.xlsx` is empty!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to do with the for loop, but:

You could create a dummy object with the same number of columns as wb, then use rbind() to join the dummy and wb to create fn2.

```
fn1 <- 'test1.xlsx'
wb <- loadWorkbook(fn1)
dummy <- wb[c(1,2),]
# set all values of dummy to whatever you want, e.g. "NA" or 0
fn2 <- rbind(dummy, wb)
saveWorkbook( fn2)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I get the error 
`Error in wb[c(1, 2), ] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable`  P.S. With the loop I was trying to add to the row number of every row so that it would appear two rows down, but it just removed all the rows.

Comment: Sounds like wb isn't loading as a data frame, but as a list or vector. Try str(wb), you may have to coerce wb before you add the rows

Answer (score 2):

So the xlsx package actually interfaces with a java library in order to pull in and modify the workbooks. The read.xlsx and write.xlsx functions are convenience wrappers to read and write data frames within R without having to manually write code to parse the individual cells and rows yourself using the java objects. The loadWorkbook and getRows functions give you access to the actual java objects, which you can then use to modify things such as cell styles.

However, if all you want to do is add a blank row to your spreadsheet before you output it, the easiest way is to add a blank row to your data frame before you export it (as Chris mentioned). You can accomplish this with the following variant on your code:

```
library("xlsx")
fn1 <- 'test1.xlsx'
fn2 <- 'test2.xlsx'

# I have added row.names=FALSE because the read.xlsx function
# does not have a parameter to include row names
write.xlsx(matrix(rnorm(25),5),fn1,row.names=FALSE)

# If you read your data back in using the read.xlsx function
# you will have a data frame rather than a series of java object references
wb <- read.xlsx(fn1,1)

# Now that we have a data frame we can add a blank row at the top
wb<-rbind.data.frame(rep("",5),wb)

# Then we write to the file using the same function as before
write.xlsx(wb,fn2,row.names=FALSE)
```

If you desire to use the advanced functionality in the java libraries, some of it is not currently implemented in the R package, and thus you will have to call it directly using .jcall. If you decide to pursue this line of action, I definitely recommend using .jmethods on the objects produced (i.e. .jmethods(rows[[1]]) which will list the available functions which you can use on the object (at the cellular level these are quite extensive).

Comment: Great answer! unfortunately, the row names are still written on the top row with two blank lines following. I need two blank lines *before* the row names